# Why is a haptic motor used for trackpad clicks on the m2 MBA?

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, design

I understand it with the iPhone SE because it would add waterproofing. But the MacBook isn't actually waterproof. So what is the benefit? And isn't it another electrical component to burn out or malfunction?

Comment: I'm not thrilled by them either, but one benefit is that the click registers with equal "depth" all over the entire surface of the trackpad. This wasn't necessarily the case with MacBooks just a few generations ago. The click was deeper at the bottom, presumably because the pivot point was at the top edge, and the mechanical actuator was on the bottom edge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trackpad provides feedback in other situations than clicks. For example, when moving tables about in Numbers using the trackpad, you will feel clicks as the tables are aligned, and so you know when to let go. There are many other examples of where such alignment indication is useful, say in drawing apps.

Also, I'd imagine some games make use of it too.

To single out one minor component for potential failure is a bit extreme compared to all the rest of the complexity of a modern MacBook. Indeed the most common formerly vulnerable mechanism, the hard disk, has now largely been replaced by SSDs. All that's left now is to find a solid-state method of moving air across heatsinks for the more powerful systems. Even that is being addressed with low power designs removing the need for fans in your aforementioned M2 MBA.

If the trackpad click fails, it's nowhere near as serious as a mechanical disk or fan failure.

Answer (score 0):

One reason is to support [Force Click](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204352), which responds with a second click if you apply further pressure.

I don't know whether it would be possible to implement this with physical switches, but if so, it would probably be pretty complex. And that wouldn't allow Force Click to be disabled (which you can do from System Preferences→Trackpad).

Implementing the click ‘in software’ is much more flexible, and also allows other forms of haptic feedback, such as letting you feel when objects are aligned. And [Apple are apparently investigating](https://www.macrumors.com/2021/03/09/apple-exploring-wider-haptic-feedback/) using it to provide further types of feedback in future.